# I turn off my Read receipt but the other person doesn’t. Will s/he get the Read notification when I’ve read her the person sent me?

Tags: iphone, ios

I wonder if the person who turns on the read receipt on imessage will get notified when I’ve read the text even though I’ve turned off my read receipt

Comment: Note: turning off read receipts is really irritating to other people. You become known as "one of those" people. You can look at a message on your lockscreen without sending the receipt for that one message if you want.

Comment: No - you control this through **your** setting. And FWIW - this comes in quite handy if you have - for example - an ex-gf who is mental.

Answer (score 1):

Read receipts are only sent by your phone when you have them on. If the other person has them on, you will continue to get receipts from them, but they will not get anything from you.